# It is time for "a next step" or "the next step"?

Tags: word-choice, articles

Which form is proper: it is time for "a next step" or "the next step"?

Comment: You might also be interested in our site for [ell.se]

Comment: Proper in what context? It's like asking what is proper: "a star" or "the star"? Both are demonstrative articles, but vary according to how specific is the article in question:

Comment: @BiVOC & 1 up voter: No, it's about the idiom.

Answer (score 3):

Both forms are grammatical.

It is unlikely that someone would say "it's time for a next step". We can see the relative prevalence of each phrase in a Google ngram:

[image: ngrams for "time for a next step" and "time for the next step"]

As is clear, Google has found approximately no authors that have ever written "time for a next step".

*The* is used over *a* primarily because "the next step" is a set phrase, but also because in a plan that has several steps, the next step is a specific one, so the definite article is used.

Comment: Why does the overwhelming evidence still leave you in doubt? The answer is *the* -- as simple as that.

Comment: @Kris what are you talking about?

Comment: @Kris: so you are saying ["lilac car" is ungrammatical](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=black+car%2Clilac+car&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblack%20car%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @RegDwigнt & 2 uppers: There's no question of grammar here.

Comment: @Kris: ah okay. So you are saying "lilac car" has no meaning. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

"a next step" is usually used when talking about any other step that may or may not have been specified earlier. whereas "the next step" is used when we know what next step we are talking about. or when we know there is "some" next step possible or specified.